# how to run multi node on the spark-shell?

Tags: apache-spark

I have been using `spark-submit` to test my codes on the multi-nodes system.
(Of course, I specified the master option as the master server address to achieve multi-nodes environment).
However, instead of using `spark-submit`, I would like to use spark-shell to test my codes on the cluster system. However, I don't know how to configure multi-nodes clusters settings on the spark-shell?

I think that just using spark-shell without changing any setups will results in the local mode.

I tried to search the info and followed the below commands.

```
scala> sc.stop()
...

scala> import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

scala> val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("shell").setMaster("my server address"))
...

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

scala> val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext = org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@567a2954
```

However, I am quite sure that I am doing right behavior for the multi-node cluster setup using spark-shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `--master` parameter of `spark-shell`? For Spark Standalone:

```
./spark-shell --master spark://master-ip:7077
```

Spark shell is just a driver, it will connect to any cluster you will write in master parameter

**Edit:**

For YARN use

```
./spark-shell --master yarn
```

Answer (score 1):

If you used `setMaster("my server address"))` and "my server address" is not `"local"`, then it won't run in local mode.

It is fine to set the master address in the code, but in production, you'd set `--master` parameter on the CLI to `spark-shell` or `spark-submit`

You can also write a separate `.scala` file, and pass that to `spark-shell -i <filename>.scala`